# refresh Rmarkdown report on user access

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Got a Rmarkdown report on a server working ok. Users are viewing this report via browser pointing to server (with rstudio server + Shiny server installed) on this URL:

```
http://RmarkdownReportServer:3838/cash_report/
```

Server is rendering **index.Rmd**, but not updated with recent data. For the report to be updated i MUST open Rstudio on server and force Knitr report.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I assumed that if data changed Rmd will be rendered using new data.

any advice on forcing server to refresh report with latest data every time user access to report site?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way using a package (funr) that wraps R code at the command line. Take a look at the example provided that covers this very issue you have:

```
Knit a HTML file using a example R markdown input from knitr package:

## get path to an example Rmd file. Assuming we have knitr installed.
## Save the filename in a BASH variable rmd
## Pipes are supported starting version 0.1.2
funr system.file package=knitr fl=examples/knitr-minimal.Rmd | funr knitr::knit2html input=-
```

Source is here:

https://github.com/sahilseth/funr

You'll have to schedule updates via cron, anyway but is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There's no use in using funr, just fire a cronjob using Rcpp:

```
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("/path_to_rmd/input.Rmd", output_file="output.html", output_dir="/path/to/outdir/")'
```